# Div height problems

Tags: css, html

I enclosed my ul in a div, but the div appears to be 1px above the ul, instead of encasing the ul which was what I wanted. I've tried doing height: auto, and width: auto, but I still get the same results. The only fix I got was to hardcode a height, which doesn't work because the size of the ul changes in every link. How can I get my div to encase my ul like I wanted?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some relevant code (and maybe a JSFiddle example) here. With only an external link, the question will have no value to future readers once the problem is solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the problem is that your `ul` is not wrapping your `li` elements, and that is because you `li`'s are floated.

If you just add the style `{ display: inline-block }` to your `ul` element, and remove the height on the `div` then it will work as expected.

Actually, you only seem to be using your `div` element to add a border to the bottom of your list, in which case you could remove it altogether, and make the style for your `ul` as follows:

```
{
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is bit  unclear, not sure which elemenet you talking about.
Any way, try something like this
in your `css` for the div remove the height and

```
.divclass{float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
.ulsize ul { overflow:hidden; }
```

and you can remove your hardcode.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your margin to `margin:24px;` instead of `margin:25px;`